# Posts page drop down is not selecting the selected page

Tags: blog, blog-page

I tried to link the blog post to new page. so i went to `settings->reading` and selected the page in `Post page` drop down and i hit save after it says `Settings saved` i can't see the selected page in the `Post page` drop down. i see only `--select--` option. Nothing is selected.

The post are not displayed in the selected page as well. What might be problem? What can i do?

Any idea of what happening would be helpful.

**Edit** after posting

When i see the value in options table through wp-admin/options.php for this `page_for_posts` option the page ID is selected. That is option has the slected page ID. but it is not showing post at the front page as well in the select box.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds strange.  Could you see the title of the page before you selected it and pressed save?  Also, what version of WordPress are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Am using wp v3.8. Also i got one clue. check my edit